# Bootstrap-Multiselect issue with form reset and checkboxes repopulating

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) for a dropdown in my application. Everything works fine except for my form reset, when I want it to revert back to the originally selected values. It's displaying the selected values as expected in the menu when it's closed (i.e. creating a list with multiple selections), but when I open the menu the checkboxes for the selected items aren't checked.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
$("#MyMenu").multiselect('refresh');
$("#MyMenu").multiselect('rebuild');
$("#MyMenu").multiselect('destroy');
```

followed by

```
$("#MyMenu").multiselect();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that the exact syntax you used? Please don't leave us to assume what else was in your code. I'm guessing you actually tried `$("#MyMenu").multiselect('refresh');`, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code to be more accurate.

Comment: Hmmm... That shoulda done it. Maybe create a demo. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here it is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st088vzL/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me it works simply with:

```
$('#id').multiselect('refresh');
```

However, it must be noted that the reset event fires before the form inputs are actually reset. Practically speaking, this means that the following won't work:

```
$('#formID').on('reset', function(){
    $('#id').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

while wrapping the call inside of an instantaneous setTimeout will work!

```
$('#formID').on('reset', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#id').multiselect('refresh');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

today i faced same issue...i did

```
$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#MyMenu").multiselect('refresh');
```

It worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error, I finally resolved it like this.

```
$('#MyMenu').multiselect('destroy');
$('#MyMenu').multiselect();

$('#MyMenu option:selected').each(function () {
    $(":checkbox[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('checked', true)
})
```

Comment: Based on your answer I did this, and it seems to work:             `$('option:selected', theMultiselect$).each(function() {
    theMultiselect$.multiselect('deselect', $(this).val());
});`

Comment: I tried that in the JSFiddle above and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

str is array from database

```
$('#dropdown').multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true,});
$("#dropdown").multiselect('deselectAll', false);
```

initialize and reset the doropdown first.

```
for(i=0; i<= str.length; i++){           
      $("#dropdown").find("option[value='"+ $.trim(str[i])+"']").prop("selected", true);
      $("#dropdown").find("option[value='"+ $.trim(str[i])+"']").attr("selected", "selected");          
}

$("#dropdown").multiselect("refresh");
```

this code will preselect the values.

Also, if you want to reset the dropdown below is the code

```
$('#dropdown').multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true,});
$("#dropdown").multiselect('deselectAll', false);

$("#dropdown").multiselect("refresh");
```

Do not forget to refresh. this code is tried and tested. works for me.

Comment: Can you format your code properly? It's unreadable at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the multiselect to its original state at page load, try:

```
// Initialize Multiselect
var msDropdownInitialSelected;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#msDropdown').multiselect();
    $('#msDropdown').multiselect('select', valuesArray);

    msDropdownInitialSelected = $('#msDropdown').val();
});

// Reset Multiselect
$('msDropdown').on('reset', function(){
    $('#msDropdown').multiselect('select', msDropdownInitialSelected);
    $('#msDropdown').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Resetting multiselect worked for me by executing below code in sequence.

```
$('#ID').multiselect('deselectAll', false);    
$('#ID').multiselect('select', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of above but following worked for me.

```
$('#ID').multiselect('deselectAll', false);    
$('#ID').multiselect('updateButtonText');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that worked for me, all others could not work.

```
$('#basicForm').on('reset', function(){ 
    // clearing the categories
    $('#project_category').select2('val', null);
    $('#project_category').attr('value', '');
});
```